# Running git init from within Google Drive dir

Tags: macos, git, terminal

I want to run **`git init`** from within Google Drive because my project folder is there but every time I do I get:

```
MacBook$ cd Google Drive
-bash: cd: Google: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also adapt your script:

```
cd Google\ Drive
# or this could work too
cd "Google Drive"
```

[This article](http://a-df.blogspot.fr/2012/07/encrypt-google-drive.html) references that directory as:

> After you've installed Google Drive you will notice a new folder in your home directory called "`Google Drive`" or more specifically "`Google\ Drive`".
>   The full path is as such:

```
/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Google\ Drive/
```

Comment: Shortcut: On MacOs it is possible to drag and drop the targeted folder into the terminal window (type "cd " first). Than you will get the right path with right spelling easily.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the space between the words "Google" and "Drive", when you do:

```
cd Google Drive
```

your shell tries to enter "Google" directory(That why the "No such file or directory" error).

Change the directory name and run the command again.